# Testing if a port was forwarded correctly in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, ip, port-forwarding

I have a Ubuntu box connected to a wifi router. This wifi router is connected to a d-link adsl modem/router. I am preparing this Ubuntu box to run a server that will use some special ports in UDP and TCP. I have setup this wifi router to put my Ubuntu box on a DMZ. So, the Ubuntu is on the DMZ of the wifi router, what means it is still on the local network of the D-link.

The big question is: how do I test, using Ubuntu, if these special ports are getting thru? I mean: there is some command I can type to check if a port is getting thru and certify that the computer is really on DMZ?

Part on the premise that the D-link is port-forwarding the ports correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say `tcpdump` on the Ubuntu box, and `netcat` on anything that should act as the client.

Comment: any examples on how to use the commands? lets say I wanna test port 443.

Comment: `tcpdump host <host> and port 443` and `nc <host> 443`.